# Display all-site reputation on user badge

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Could we have all-site reputation added to user badges on the various SE sites--possibly as a tool tip when hovering over the current site's rep?

It would be nice to have access to a sum of all-site reputation for blog badges as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have the flair that do a cumul of all of your reputation:
But it does work only for the sites where you have more than 200 rep.

[image]

No tooltip for the moment.

Comment: Thanks--that's helpful for number two. As fo the first, I'm particularly thinking of when you ask/answer questions on a site that you're relatively new to, so that folks can see your experience with the system as a whole.